# シンボリックリンクを削除したら403エラーになった

Tags: linux, centos, apache, amazon-linux

環境はAmazon Linux、Apache2.4.25、PHP7です。

シンボリックを削除したら、200で今までウェブから見れていたphpファイル（login.php）が、403で見れなくなりました。原因がわからないため、教えていただけると助かります。

【経緯】
１．もともとabcという名前のリポジトリを、理由あってdefというリポジトリに変更しました。
２．移行期間にabcという名前のシンボリックリンクを作成し、defにリンクしました。
３．しばらくそのまま運用。
４．移行が終わったと判断し、abcという名前のシンボリックリンクをunlinkで削除。
５．phpファイル（login.php）が403になって見れなくなりました。

移行先であるdefリポジトリの中のlogin.phpのパーミッションは、下記の通り、その他ユーザー（Apache）は閲覧権限のみです。

```
-rw-r--r--
```

少ない情報で申し訳ありませんが、「ここら辺のパーミッション確認した方が良いよ」とか、「abcシンボリックが別の場所から参照されているのではないか」など、アドバイスいただけるとありがたいです。

必要な情報があれば追記します。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: apacheの設定周りを追記できますか？もともとのapacheの設定はどうなっているか、移行のときにどのような設定をしたか、今はどのような設定になっているか

Comment: ご指摘いただいた通りapacheの設定を確認した所、Require all grantedの<Directory>のパスが古いシンボリックのままになっていました。

Comment: 修正した所、これまで通り見れるようになりました。

Comment: 大変助かりました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 自己解決した場合は、自分自身で回答を書き、その回答を承認して下さい。詳しくは[「自分の質問に回答できますか?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)をご覧下さい。

Answer (score 1):

コメント欄で指摘を頂いた通りApacheの設定を確認した所、Require all granted の `<Directory>` のパスが古いシンボリックのままになっていたので、こちらを修正することで正常に表示されるようになりました。

---

*この投稿は [@key さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/47556/%e3%82%b7%e3%83%b3%e3%83%9c%e3%83%aa%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%83%aa%e3%83%b3%e3%82%af%e3%82%92%e5%89%8a%e9%99%a4%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89403%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%ab%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f#comment48866_47556) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*